# Are functions still continuous even with removable discontinuities?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, continuity

If we define a continuous function as a function that is continuous at all points in its domain, then would a removable discontinuity not impact this?

For example consider the function $f(x) = x$. It is clearly continuous at every point in its domain, which is all real numbers.

But now let's have $f(x) = x \cdot \frac{x-2}{x-2}$ which means the function is undefined at $x=2$, but still equivalent to $f(x)=x$ everywhere else, so we exclude that point $x=2$ from the domain.

The domain is now something like $(-\infty, 2) \cup (2, \infty)$. Continuity at a point usually means the limits exist and they equal the function's value at that point. The number $2$ is not in the domain so we only have to consider numbers to the left and to the right of $2$, and no matter what number we pick, they will be defined and have limits equaling those values.

So would we still call such a function "continuous" despite having this $f(2)$ undefined?

Comment: A function that is continuous with a removable discontinuity is continuous *on its domain*, but it is not continuous at the point of discontinuity, as it is not even defined there!  However, it can be extended to a new continuous function by removing the singularity.

Comment: I thought "continuous on its domain" was essentially the same as saying the function itself is a "continuous function"

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the point that I was making.  I was just trying emphasize the fact that the domain matters.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Would the same notion apply to infinite discontinuities, since their asymptotes are usually points excluded from the domain as well? Are jump discontinuities really the only thing that can make a function "discontinuous"?

Comment: Yes.  We only care about points that are in the domain of the function.

Comment: So "removable discontinuity" and "infinite/essential discontinuity" are somewhat misleading terminologies? I guess this is why I've heard some people advise using "removable singularity" instead, but we still have "infinite discontinuity" unless there's a better name for that too.

Comment: In the Wikipedia page you link below, it is written that "The term removable discontinuity is sometimes an abuse of terminology for cases in which the limits in both directions exist and are equal, while the function is undefined at the point $x_0$. This use is abusive because continuity and discontinuity of a function are concepts defined only for points in the function's domain. Such a point not in the domain is properly named a removable singularity."  A removable discontinuity isn't *really* a discontinuity. :\

Comment: That paragraph is what led me to ask this question actually! I do still wonder if "infinite discontinuity" is an abuse of terminology as well.

Comment: Possibly, though possibly not.  If a function has a removable discontinuity, then it can be extended to a continuous function by "pluggin the hole".  This is not possible for functions with vertical asymptotes, unless (1) $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a^{-}} f(x) = +\infty$ (or $-\infty$---they should have the same infinite limit), and (2) we extend the domain of the function to include these points at infinity.  Alternatively, we could work on the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's also a use of terminology I don't understand. If we say the function is continuous even with the removable discontinuity, and then we "extend it to a continuous function by plugging in the hole", are we implying it was not continuous before, or are we really saying "we extend it to yet another continuous function by plugging the hole"

Comment: The latter.  The extension is a new function, with a different, larger domain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, of course. The only thing that matters for continuity are those points at which the function is defined. What occurs outside the domain is irrelevant.

Comment: So discontinuous functions only really arise when we have jump discontinuities and essential/infinite discontinuities?

Comment: No. THere's also that case in which the limit at a point doies not exist, Take, for instance $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ if $x\neq0$, with $f(0)=0$. It is discontinuous at $0$ because $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: (I had assumed that example was a form of an essential discontinuity but I could be mistaken)

Comment: @user525966 I don't think I've ever heard of essential discontinuities.

Comment: I had been going by this definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity

Comment: @user525966 The you were right from the start,

Comment: If we had changed your definition to exclude $0$ from the domain then it would become a continuous function?

Comment: @user525966 Yes, it would.

Comment: @immibis The function that I defined in my first comment *is* defined at $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that's what I get for skim-reading

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So according to your answer we cannot talk of continuity of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at x=0

Comment: @LalitTolani Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The function is continuous, because it is still continuous in every point of its (now smaller) domain $(-\infty,2)\cup(2, \infty)$.

I am aware that there are other "definitions" of continuity. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) is confusing in that sense, as it gives a number of definitions that are equivalent to each other, and *some that are not*:

> The most common and restrictive definition is that a function is continuous if it is continuous at all real numbers.

Ugh! Come on, it means that a function not defined on the whole $\mathbb R$ cannot be continuous!

I am sure there are other sources of information that muddle the waters more than they make things clear...

Obviously, if you look at the (continuous) function $f(x)=x, f:\mathbb R\setminus\{2\}\to\mathbb R$ - its *graph* is not connected, has two components, but that is *not* what we call discontinuity. A discontinuity would be a point $x_0$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\ne f(x_0)$, and to even check this condition you must be able to calculate $f(x_0)$, i.e. the function $f$ must be defined in $x_0$ (in our case, $x_0\ne 2$).

Thus, my conclusion for the OP is this:

- Take the universally accepted definition of continuity: the function is continuous if it is continuous at every point of its domain. Or any definition equivalent to that one. (I personally like the topological one, where the function is continuous if the preimage of any open subset of the codomain is an open subset of the domain.)
- Accept that the graph of a continuous function need not be a connected set (in, say, $\mathbb R^2$) - though, obviously, it *will* be if the domain of the function itself is connected.
- Accept that in maths' education there are other non-equivalent definitions of continuity floating around; fight them with arguments (even if it seems like attacking windmills).

Comment: I think the "intuitive" definition would require that the domain be convex, but not necessarily cover all reals.

Answer (score 2):

Would like to add to the other answers:

Agreed that a function which is continuous on the domain that it's defined is "continuous". However, going by the title and generalizing a bit depending on your definition of *removable discontinuities* and then depending on the function, that function may still *not* be continuous. In your question description you talk about if f(2) is *undefined*, but that may not be the ONLY case where you have removable discontinuities.

A definition may allow a function with removable discontinuities to be defined *at* the discontinuous points. For example, f(x) = x for all x in R except x = 2, for which f(x) = 1. This function is truly *discontinuous*, and the removable discontinuity is truly a discontinuity. This is similar to how one might use/make sense of the term "infinite" discontinuity", for example f(x) = 1/x for non-zero x, and f(x) = 0 for x = 0. In this case, f is a discontinuous function.

Of course, the terms probably originated because people *were* talking about the whole Real number line instead of the domains in which the functions are defined, and for better or for worse (probably for worse) the naming stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct but note that in some context a function is defined to be continuos if its domain is an interval, and it is continuous at every point of that interval.

Here you can find a good source from MIT for a full classification [Continuity and Discontinuity](http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.01_Fall%202014/Supplementary%20notes/01c.pdf).